# In countries where freedom of expression is limited and the constitution prohibits political participation, what are the options?

Tags: geopolitics

There are many countries where freedom of expression is restricted in various ways and certain people or all people are restricted or not even allowed legally to participate in politics of any kind. It is often very difficult for the international community to hold these countries accountable, and by the time they act, it may be too late for many due to the laws punishing political leaders who chose to defy the regime.

What kind of politics can be done under these circumstances? What kind of effective political actions can the citizens of such repressed regimes take to demand and express their universal rights under such circumstances?

Comment: In what sense meaningful? Please clarify? How to you measure the meaningfulness?

Answer (score 4):

This question has been downvoted and received close votes. I suspect that is because it asks for a sweeping **general** answer when it will take a very close look at the **specifics**.

Political philosophers have thought about the concept of [right to revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_of_revolution), about [just war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_war_theory) and [responsibility to protect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsibility_to_protect). The decision to take violent action depends on the injustice that is opposed, compared to the suffering that even well-intentioned violence will inevitably bring. There is also the question if there is popular support for any regime change -- if a (duped? fanatical?) population backs the unjust government, it gets much harder to justify action because success is much less likely.

1. Estimate the reaction of your fellow citizens and the world community to your **perceived** oppression. Do they see things the same way you do? Some of the greatest atrocities have happened when revolutionaries were so convinced of their own understanding of the [volonte general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_will) that they thought everybody else had to be forced along. Step outside of your own filter bubble.
   There are people in democratic countries who think that vaccination programs or fossil fuel use are oppressive. They are minorities in their populations, but perhaps not among the people they talk to every day.
2. Estimate the reaction of your government to acts of peaceful [civil disobedience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_disobedience), and the likelihood of your fellow citizens to go along. A [general strike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_strike) can topple most governments, even oppressive ones, if it is truly general.
   If the citizens would not join you, consider if your estimate in 1. was wrong.
3. If you truly think that the overthrow of your government is justified and feasible, be prepared to become a martyr to the cause. Your government will brand you as a terrorist.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking if there is a way to do politics in such regimes without any personal harm (like imprisonment, torture or death), then the answer is no.

Otherwise, the popular solution to dealing with an oppressive regime is to fight it violently by instigating a revolution. Ofcourse, the retaliation by those in power is to often kill the revolutionaries.

A less popular method is non-violent resistance, with the most popular and effective one based on [Gandhi's political philosophy](https://www.mkgandhi.org/) - you work within the system, foster relationships, and push for systematic reforms patiently. It's easy to forget that India got freedom 3+ decades after Gandhi took over the reins of India's freedom movement. Often the repercussion for such political actions is jail time. For e.g., during India's freedom movement, Gandhi was sent to jail many times and spent nearly 6 years (2,338 days) of his life imprisoned, while Nehru (India's first Prime Minister) lost nearly 9 year (3259 days) of his life in prison. Nelson Mandela, in South Africa, spent 27 years of his life in prison.